# I'd like to display different image to the first 3 items in my list

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

Display different image to the first three item in `LIstView` from the image displayed to the rest of the list. It doesn't work with my adapter class , it is just display the image in the layout to all items 
This is my code

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    // Constructor which is called when the custom adapter is created
    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        // Select the layout for the cell
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //inflate the xml file to a view object and must be used as shown below
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // create the row view
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false);

        // Link the widgets on the layout with the Java codes
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // Set the content of the text based on the values string in the main activity
        textView.setText(values[position]);


        if ( position == 0 || position == 1 || position == 2)
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
        else
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.second);



        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting image from Sqlite fro api ? You can show three image or number of by animation or setting a custom layout to display different image by using  SQL query

Comment: using Order By ASC ( or DSC) Limit 3

Comment: Then you will get 3 image path and then change that Image path into Bitmap and then finally set  that Bitmap to ImageView  :-)

Comment: can you check that you haven't have the same image with different name? (check also all the drawable folders)

Comment: You cannot do this this way.
You need to have ViewTypes.
Override getViewTypeCount and getViewType.

If you need some more info on this, just ask

Comment: is there something wrong with the code ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it is simpler than you'd expect, just change your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a `BaseAdapter` instead of `ArrayAdapter`. An array adapter is mostly used to bind one field with one set of values. If your listview requires customization i would suggest you use BaseAdapter instead.

This is from the android documentation:

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary
>   objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id
>   **references a single TextView**. **If you want to use a more complex
>   layout, use the constructors that also takes a field id.** That field id
>   should reference a TextView in the larger layout resource.

That being said, it's still possible to use an `ArrayAdapter`, you just need to use another constructor in the `ArrayAdapater`, as sugested in the documentation. So instead of using `super(context, R.layout.list_layout, values);` in your constructor, use `super(context, R.layout.list_layout, R.id.label,  values);`. You need to pass the textview id in the constructor if you want your arrayadapter to work with images. Also, i would change `if ( position == 0 || position == 1 || position == 2)` to  `if ( position < 3)` because it looks cleaner :)

Comment: Better choice is actually Recycler and its adapters

Comment: Indeed. I did not suggest it because the Recyclerview doesn't use the same types of adapters, but it's the best way to go for performance and customizability.

Comment: Thank you Chris , I tried it but it didn't work either

Comment: What went wrong? Is there any build output or a screenshot of the result?

Comment: it just display the list with all items have the image in the list_layout